# Haskell is evaluating much faster then I thought it would (no complaints)

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I wrote the following to check if a number is prime:

```
factorsOf :: Int -> [Int]
factorsOf n = [factor | factor <- [2..sqrtOfN], n `rem` factor == 0]
    where sqrtOfN = round . sqrt $ fromIntegral $ n+1

isPrime :: Int -> Bool
isPrime n
    | factorsOf n == [] = True
    | otherwise = False
```

and it works, but I noticed something weird. If I run factorsOf on a large number (say 100000001), it takes a few seconds to calculate all the factors. If I run isPrime on the same number though, it will return almost immediately if it finds a factor. Does Haskell actually keep track of the condition that a function will return to to support (I'm assuming) lazy evaluation? Thats awesome if it's true.

Comment: The guard in `isPrime` is only interested in whether `factorsOf` contains any elements at all. As soon as one factor is found, the result of `isPrime` can be determined. There is no need to evaluate the whole list of factors.

Comment: Try comparing the performance with a large prime such as 1000000007 as the input.

Comment: @Xeo That's what I thought; that's pretty cool. If I wanted to learn more about this, would any article about lazy evaluation do, or are guards a special case?

Comment: @Niklas B. I'm assuming it would take as long as the factorsOf call?

Comment: `factorsOf  100000001` is `[17]` and it computes instantly. Well, if you are running on a toaster, then perhaps, but on a modern desktop computer, no 32-bit number is "large" for this calculation. Want a large list of factors? Try `factorsOf $ product [1..17]`, but replace `Int` with `Integer` to get arbitrary-precision arithmetic. For a *really really* large list, try `product [1..20]`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Actually you should probably use a prime in the order of 10^15 for any kind of measurable runtime. But yes, the work should be the same.

Comment: Well it's still a bit too long even for a tablet on sleep pills. Are you using Hugs by any chance?

Comment: @n.m. I just double checked it, and it's running considerably faster now; even on the same setting. It took 0.08 secs to evaluate factorsOf 10000000000. Idk why it why it was derping before. (And idk what Hugs is. A compiler? I'm using GHCI)

Comment: Ghci is an interpreter. Ghc is the compiler - write a function main :: IO () and compile with -O2

Comment: Hugs is an older Haskell interpreter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, `isPrime` only needs to evaluate the result of `factorsOf` deeply enough to determine if it is an empty list or not. You could write `isPrime` more idiomatically like this:

```
isPrime = null . factorsOf
```

where null is simply

```
null (_:_) = False
null _ = True
```

Note that as soon as `null` can pattern match on a `(:)` constructor, it returns a result without evaluating the rest of the list.

This means only the `factorsOf` only needs to compute the first factor for `isPrime` to return, whereas `factorsOf` by itself will compute the entire list.

Answer (score 1):

The basic principle of laziness is that nothing is evaluated unless it is really really needed. Really needed in your case means that the first function must return so that the other function gets its input. You can read more about Haskell's Laziness [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Laziness)